# How to put two tables next to each other in html but without using the tag "style"?

Tags: html

I have made two tables for a project but I don't know how to put them next to each other without using "style", any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in another table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        table 1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        table 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

see here
https://jsfiddle.net/ewyoam2L/

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use styles but I would really recommend using CSS Grid instead of tables. It's much easier to change rows and columns around once you learn the basics, it doesn't require complex nesting to do things like place two tables next to each other, and it works great with responsive designs:

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.grid > div{
   background: lightgrey;
   padding:20px;
}

.grid .rowspan{
   grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div class='rowspan'>Five</div>
</div>
<div class='grid'>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div class='rowspan'>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```